# MS Expression Studio Fails to Detect MP4 Video

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, video-codecs, microsoft-expression

I have imported a H.264 MP4 video file into Microsoft Expression Encoder 4, however when I convert the video to the IIS Smooth Streaming VC-1 format, it only has audio with a green screen. How do I fix? Is there a way to force it to use different codecs?

Interestingly, if I skip ahead in the Preview pane, the video is displayed, but if I play from start, it remains a green screen without video - which is the output result.

Codec info:

[image]

Expression Encoder:

[image]